# URL issue in Droplets and Django

Tags: python, django

I purchased a domain name from GoDaddy and I linked it to my Droplets server's A records.

So far everything was working fine, it loaded the static files, it loaded the home view properly, everything was going great until I tried to go to a different part of my site (for example '...com/login/'). I ran into this weird issue where the site would only load the home page view, whatever URL I typed in it wouldn't serve anything else. Maybe the problem is that I developed the site using Django 2, and the Droplets Ubuntu server only uses Django 1.10, maybe.

Anyway if anyone has any kind of solution to this it would be greatly appreciated, I've been trying to solve this problem for about 2 weeks now, thanks! (Also if anyone knows how to upgrade to Django 2 on droplets, post that too please, thanks!)

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.Home, name='home'),
    url('upload/', views.up_page, name='upload'),
    url('follow/', views.follow, name='fol'),
    url('un_follow/', views.un_follow, name='un_fol'),
    url('reset/', views.reset, name='res'),
    url('search/', views.search_page, name='srch_page'),
 ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: can you paste your urls.py.

Comment: This usually happens because of ordering of url patterns. If home pattern is the first pattern, then chances are it is matching every url.

Comment: So it's the ordering that could be causing the problem?

Comment: Nothing has actually changed in terms of  URL routing in version 2. There is just an extra way of doing it. What OP has done was wrong in 1.11 and is still wrong in 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not terminated the regexp for your home view.

```
url('^$', views.Home, name='home'),
```

Note this would work exactly the same in both versions 1.11 and 2.0. But really you should be running your code locally before deploying, where you would be able to see that it is broken.

Also, if for some reason you really can't upgrade your server to 2.0, there's nothing stopping you running 1.11 locally for development too.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! The main reason I was confused is because when I ran it locally the site worked perfectly, URL's and all.